# ASN.1 REAL binary base 2 encoding mantissa normalization

Tags: c++, asn.1, der

I am trying to DER encode REAL data in binary 2 base form using C++. I calculate the mantissa and exponent with the following algorithm.

sample data = 32.3125

1. using C++ `std::frexp` function, extract `double` mantissa and `int` exponent.
   mantissa `0.5048828125` exponent `6`
2. Convert the mantissa to integer by multiplying by 2 and decreasing exponent by 1 till integer mantissa is got.
   mantissa `517` exponent `-4`
3. Finally the data is encoded as
   `09 04 80(binary 2 base) FC(exp) 02 05(mantissa)`

Is this encoding correct? In the standard(X.690-0207), it talks about mantissa representation in a different form.

> 8.5.6 When binary encoding is used (bit 8 = 1), then if the mantissa M is non-zero, it shall be represented by a sign S, a positive integer
> value N and a binary scaling factor F, such that: M = S × N × 2F
>
> In the Canonical Encoding Rules and the Distinguished Encoding Rules
> normalization is specified and the mantissa (unless it is 0) needs to
> be repeatedly shifted until the least significant bit is a 1.

Is this necessary to convert the mantissa in this format and encode N and F, or is it ok to keep the F as '0' as in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encoding is correct.  Note that the requirements for DER are covered in X.690 11.3, and you have met them (you are using base 2, your mantissa is odd, and F = 0).  F != 0 is only ever needed when encoding using base 8 or 16.